# Select a 2d cut-through of 3D data?

Tags: r

I've get density data from `ks::kde` function which is a 3D model. 
Then I receive a value for the first of the 3 dimensions so I could take a flat slice of the data and operate on 2d slice of the 3d data, afterwards.

Till now, when I needed a 1D line I would do

```
splinefun(predict(my_kde_3d_result, x=rep(0, 10, 0.1))
```

but for 2D slice that's a very slow n^2 challange for `predict`, and as for `splinefun`, I don't even find a version for 2D functions.

What do I have left?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example that others can base their answers on. Otherwise we will have to guess many details and probably not end up with anything useful.

Comment: Doing a predict into vector into line is a very roundabout way of finding a line when you can directly pull the densities via my_kde_3d_result$eval.points and my_kde_3d_result$estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an example:

```
library(ks)
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000),z=rnorm(1000))
k1 <- kde(as.matrix(d))
```

Now to grab a slice corresponding to `x==-2`

```
target.x <- -2
w <- which.min(abs(k1$eval.points[[1]]-target.x))
contour(k1$estimate[w,,])
```

Obviously you can do this for any particular `x`, `y`, or `z` value: if you want a slice that's not parallel to the `xyz` planes it gets harder ... If you know in advance that you will want to predict for (e.g.) `x==-2` you can set the `eval.points` argument to `kde` accordingly.

Comment: This is an interesting idea but what can I do if i need to choose a real x like x=-2.00034?

Comment: As I said (or tried to say): if you're satisfied with an approximate slice you can use the code above, but with `target.x <- -2.00034`.  If you need it to be exact, you can specify `eval.points` in your call to `kde`: see the help file (`?kde`).